# Javascript function realoding page

Tags: javascript, function, flask, hyperlink

I wat to create a webapp via flask and javascript. I have a question in the javascript related field. I have this two function:

```
function calculateBMI(){
    let height = document.getElementById("bmiHeight").value;
    let weight = document.getElementById("bmiWeight").value;

    let bmi = parseFloat(weight) / (parseFloat(height) * parseFloat(height));

    let result = document.getElementById("bmiResult");

    result.innerText = "Your BMI is:" + bmi;
}
```

```
function calculateWater(){
    let weight = document.getElementById("waterWeight").value;
    let result = document.getElementById("waterResult");
    result.innerText = "Your water requirement is: " + parseInt(weight)*30 + "ml";
}
```

This functions are both actived by a button tag, like this

```
<button value = calculate onclick="calculateBMI()">Calculate</button>
<button value = calculate onclick="calculateWater()">Calculate</button>
```

With that said, I can't understand why when I calculate BMI, the pages reload and add an ? to the hyperlink, so I can't see the resoult. It doesn't happend whit the water function, that works properly. I can't understant if I made some stupid error, that I don't know. If you can,m please help me

Comment: Are these buttons part of a form? If so, they would _submit_ that form, when you click them. Add `type="button"`, if you want them to be mere click buttons. (No, that doesn't explain why both behave differently - but I don't think that _can_ be explained with the code snippets you have shown so far, and would rather need a [mre].)

Comment: Javascript code looks fine to me. maybe something else in the html code? Could you post the full code to an online editor for us to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your functions to create the working code. You can investigate it. There is no page reload.
If your code reloads it might be something else, you should check it carefully. You might have a form tag and it also might reload your page.

```js
function calculateBMI(){
    let height = document.getElementById("bmiHeight").value;
    let weight = document.getElementById("bmiWeight").value;

    let bmi = parseFloat(weight) / (parseFloat(height) * parseFloat(height));

    let result = document.getElementById("bmiResult");

    result.innerText = "Your BMI is:" + bmi;
}
function calculateWater(){
    let weight = document.getElementById("waterWeight").value;
    let result = document.getElementById("waterResult");
    result.innerText = "Your water requirement is: " + parseInt(weight)*30 + "ml";
}
```

```html
<label for="bmiHeight">BMI Height</label><input id="bmiHeight">
<label for="bmiWeight">BMI Weight</label><input id="bmiWeight">
<br>
<button value = calculate onclick="calculateBMI()">Calculate</button>
<h2 id="bmiResult"></h2>
<br>

<label for="waterWeight">Water weight</label><input id="waterWeight">
<br>
<button value = calculate onclick="calculateWater()">Calculate</button>
<h2 id="waterResult"></h2>
```